# Nginx issue - special characters after URL

Tags: nginx, web-server, web-hosting, website

My website has trailing #! something like [www.mywebsite.com/#](http://www.mywebsite.com/#)!

I want to redirect this to 404. There are server block and location blocks in my conf.d/mywebsite.com.conf

```
server {
    server_name    mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    root           /var/www/mywebsite/public;
    index          index.php index.html;

    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location /blog {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        }
    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  3;
    gzip_types       text/plain text/css application/javascript image/*;

    client_max_body_size 10m;

}
server {
    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After the hash (#) is never sent the server. Therefore, it doesn't make sense write a rule for the URL part is never sent the server to begin with hash (#).

Let's say you have these URLs:

```
site.com/my_data_here
site.com/my_data_here#xyz
```

You can write some conditions for the `my_data_here` part. The browser doesn't send the `xyz` parameter to the server.